# Can I check for p2 updates without having permissions?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2

In attempting to use p2, whenever I execute an UpdateOperation.resolveModal call, I get the following error:

**Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency**

After doing a little research I found out that this is a very poor way of equinox informing you that you don't have sufficient privileges to execute that command because when I run as administrator, updates work without a hitch.

My question is this. Is there a programmatic way in Eclipse for p2 to check to see if updates are available without considering whether the user actually has the permissions to perform the update?

Comment: Why do operating system permissions play a role here? I suppose that you don't have a standalone installation in your user home, do you? This information is missing in your question - please edit it to add this information.

Comment: I actually figured out after much digging that the call to resolveModal doesn't require permissions. When I ran as administrator initially, I didn't have the update site set up correctly. So the "working without a hitch" ended up being that way because the site hadn't been set up. After setting it up, I realized that in both the case of running as a normal user and as admin updates were discovered as being available. I just couldn't perform the updates as a regular user, which is all I needed to know. Thanks for your response though. I'm a p2 novice, so a bit of it is trial-and-error as I go.